# Is it possible to request for push notifications for a second time on IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push, push-notification

If a user said NO to push notifications the first time, i'm not sure how to request that again at a latter time, is there a way to do this?

Thanks so much!

EDIT:

What i mean is that When the user uses the app for the first time, you can request the user to allow our app to send push notifications, if the user sais NO, i don't know if i can request the same thing at a latter time. Hope i made myself clear this time

Comment: Push notifications can not be requested. They are sent by a server. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're referring to registration - the dialog that pops up when you request push notification registration for the first time.

You do not have control over when this dialog appears. You cannot 'request' it to appear a second time - what you can do is advise users to go into the Settings app, where they can manually enable push notifications for your app. The next time your app runs the push notification registration will succeed.

Hope that helps!